# Как сделать правильные окончания слов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать правильные окончания слов, например: 1 товар, 2 товара, 5 товаров и т. д.
Сейчас на данный момент написан скрипт просто вывода все значения в слово "товар", строка.

***В шапке количество товаров***

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var BasketItems = $('.basket-small-fly .text_number').text(),
      BasketCost = $('.basket-small-fly .basket-coupon-block-total-price-current').text();
    $('#win8_wrapper').hide()
    $('.dropdown-block').click(function() {
      if ($('.dropdown-list', this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('i', this).removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
        $('.dropdown-list', this).slideUp(0);
        $('.dropdown-list', this).removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $('i', this).removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
        $('.dropdown-list', this).slideDown(300);
        $('.dropdown-list', this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
    $('.dropdown-list li').click(function() {
      var count_item = $('.count-item', this).text();
      $('li.selected .count-item').text(count_item);
      var item_id = $(this).closest('.item-block').attr('data-id');
      changeItemBasket(item_id, count_item);

    });
    //Проверка промокода
    $('.one_click_buy_id_coupon-button').click(function() {
      var coupon = $('#one_click_buy_id_coupon').val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/include/ajax-basket/oneclick_addcoupon.php", // куда отправляем
        type: "post", // метод передачи
        dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
        data: {
          "coupon": coupon
        },
        // после получения ответа сервера
        success: function(data) {
          $('.coupon-answer').html('');
          $('.coupon-answer').html(data.result); // выводим ответ сервера
        }
      });
    });
    $('.cart-val').text(BasketItems + " товар"); //В шапке количество товаров
    $('.summ-val').text(BasketCost); //В шапке стоимость корзины
    if (BasketCost == "") {
      $('.summ-val').text("0 рублей");
    }
    $('.like-val').text(<?=$CountWishBasket?>); //В шапке количество избранных
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Вам надо написать свою функцию которая будет в аргумент принимать кол-во товаров (BasketItems) и возвращать его + слово. Прежде всего - подумайте сами в каких случаях товар, в каких товаров и т.п.. Когда сформировали кейсы - переносите их в код. Если что-то не получается - пишите, за вас сделать это вы не по адресу.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

То есть вы имеете ввиду склонение слова, по определенному количеству товара?

```
function morph(int, array) {
    return (array = array || ['товар', 'товара', 'товаров']) && array[(int % 100 > 4 && int % 100 < 20) ? 2 : [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2][(int % 10 < 5) ? int % 10 : 5]];
}
console.log(morph(1)); // товар
console.log(morph(2)); // товара
console.log(morph(5)); // товаров
```

Склоняться будет так:
`товар` - 1, 21, 31, 41, 51 ... и т. д.
`товара` - 2, 3, 4, 22, 23, 24, 32 ... и т. д.
`товаров` - 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10-20 ... и т. д.

Comment: Да склонение слова, по определенному количеству товара. А подскажите пожалуйста куда вставить данный код? И подойдет ли он мне?

Comment: @Валерий, У вас есть `$('.cart-val').text(BasketItems + " товар");`, суда и вставляйте. Должно получиться, что-то типо:  `$('.cart-val').text(BasketItems + " " + morph(BasketItems, ['товар', 'товара', 'товаров']));`.